# How to get textarea value with lxml python

Tags: python, lxml, lxml.html

With this python code i can get whole html source

```
import mechanize
import lxml.html
import StringIO

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [("User-agent","Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.13")]
sign_in = br.open("http://target.co.uk")
#the login url
br.select_form(nr = 0) 
#accessing form by their index.
#Since we have only one form in this example, nr =0.
br.select_form(nr=0)
#Alternatively you may use this instead of the above line 
#if your form has name attribute available.
br["username"] = "myusername"
#the key "username" is the variable that takes the username/email value
br["password"] = "myp4sw0rd"
#the key "password" is the variable that takes the password value
logged_in = br.submit()   
#submitting the login credentials
logincheck = logged_in.read()
#reading the page body that is redirected after successful login
if "logout" in logincheck:
    print "Login success, you just logged in."
else:
    print "Login failed"
#printing the body of the redirected url after login
coding1_content = br.open("https://www.target.co.uk/levels/coding/1").read() 
#accessing other url(s) after login is done this way


tree = lxml.html.parse(io.StringIO(coding1_content)

for ta in tree.findall("//textarea"):
    if not ta.get("name"):
        print(ta.text)

if "textarea" in coding1_content:
    print "Textarea found."
else:
    print "Textarea not found."
```

but what i need is get content of first `textarea` tag which dont have name, my html source is like below

```
........
........
<textarea>this, is, what, i, want</textarea>
<textarea name="answer">i don't need it</textarea>
........
........
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

According to the lxml documentation you can access the forms of a html-object by accessing the forms property:

```
form_page = fromstring('''some html code with a <form>''')
form = form_page.forms[0] # to get the first form
form.fields # these are the fields
```

see more here: http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html -> Forms

Comment: actually the html source come from 
coding1_content = br.open("https://www.target.co.uk/protected/page/1").read()
not file, so i need to open url and get the source then scrape textarea content

Comment: If you manage to read the html page into a string and get i parsed by lxml you can access the form.

Comment: you could also use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup which is built on top of lxml and is a special html parser.

Comment: form_page = lxml.html.fromstring(coding1_content)
form = form_page.forms[0]
print form.fields[0].value

just trying above code and i get KeyError: 'No input element with the name 0' , actually the first textarea dont have any attribute so its like <textarea>something, i, want, to, get, here</textarea>, where is my mistake bro ?

Comment: maybe there is no form surrounding it. you could also try out http://lxml.de/cssselect.html to use a css selector or the xpath that the other guys mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML is

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form>
      <textarea>this, is, what, i, want</textarea>
      <textarea name="answer">i don't need it</textarea>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

you can get the `textarea` content like this:

```
import io
import lxml.html

html = "..."
tree = lxml.html.parse(io.StringIO(html)
for ta in tree.findall("//textarea"):
    if not ta.get("name"):
        print(ta.text)
```

Output:

```
this, is, what, i, want
```

Comment: actually the html source come from 
coding1_content = br.open("https://www.target.co.uk/protected/page/1").read()
not file, so i need to open url and get the source then scrape textarea content

Comment: You can use `io.StringIO` to parse from a string.

Comment: i did your code but i get error shown in this picture http://prntscr.com/6r6jlb, whats wrong bro ?

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29512047/edit) and include the complete code of `alpha2.py`.

Comment: Your indention is wrong. The line `print(ta.text)` must be indented *two* levels.

Comment: just indented like you said but still error bro like my picture. looks like weird error. may i chat you bro ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74784/discussion-between-dark-cyber-and-tichodroma).

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way to get all `<textarea>` not having HTML attribute `name`, that is using [`xpath()`](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method) method :

```
.....
for t in tree.xpath(".//textarea[not(@name)]"):
    print t.text
```

while `findall()` only support subsets of the XPath language, `xpath()` has full XPath 1.0 support. For example, as demonstrated in this particular case, `xpath()` supports `not()` and `findall()` doesn't.